# can't see wordpress after installing SSL Cert on CENTOS 7

Tags: wordpress, apache, ssl, https, centos7

I have a VPS account that uses CENTOS 7.
I was able to install Apache, MariaDB, PHP, and WordPress.
Everything was working great until I installed an SSL Cert from that SSLS.com/COMMODO.
Basically when I go to my domainname.com or IP address, I no longer see WordPress, I see the default apache page.

in in the ssl.conf file I have "DocumentRoot "/var/www/"", i know wordpress is in the var/www/html but when I change it to that
wordpress works but ssl does not thanks

Comment: Without SSL is in a VirtualHost for `*:80` probably.  Copy the entire VirtualHost block and modify it for `*:443`.  Then add all the SSL and certificates configurations in there.  Finally add `Listen 443`.  Without seeing your configuration, can't do much more.

Comment: I think I figured it out, I’ll post my intense modifications when I get home today.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did.
I deleted wordpress (copied the wp-config.php file). Then I reinstalled wordpress and replaced the wp-config.php file
with the old one.

In the httpd.conf file I put:
`<VirtualHost *:80>  ServerName mycoolexampledomain.com`  ServerAlias mycoolexampledomain.com

Redirect permanent / https://mycoolexampledomain.com/

AllowOverride All
    Require all granted

<Directory "/var/www">
AllowOverride All
# Allow open access:
Require all granted

**used the allowed overide in the /var/www/html too

in the ssl.conf

## General setup for the virtual host, inherited from global configuration

DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
ServerName mycoolexampledomain.com:443

## General setup for the virtual host, inherited from global configuration

DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
ServerName mycoolexampledomain.com:443

SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/domaincoolexample_com.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/domaincoolexample_key.key        <- commodo send this to me in a .txt file but i renamed it
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/domaincoolexample.ca-bundle

then the .htaccess file I changed it so apache user is the owner

then in the wordpress settings I made it go to: https://mycooldomainexample.com on the two general settings `

Comment: I am not sure if its by VPS Provider but its kind of slow and some times does not load the website or allowed me to connect with SSH. I am using MariaDB 10 and PHP 8